# Formulas Changed to Reference Last Row When I Close and Open Excel File

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, cells

I have no idea what is causing this issue, but when I reopen an Excel file, formulas that reference cells will change the reference cells at the very end of the sheet.

Example: 
Super simple spread sheet adding A1 and A2 in A3

[image]

When I close the file and reopen the file, I can't select any options in the ribbon, and the formula in A3 has been changed to reference cells A1048575 and A1048576 instead of A1 and A2.

[image]

This happens to any existing Excel file that I try to open. Also, this can happen with columns as well, like the furthermost column in a spreadsheet, changes to XFD. Say I have a number in E1 that will change to XFD1 and columns A-D will change to XEZ-XFC.

Any help resolving this issue is much appreciated.

Comment: In the Review tab, is the workbook shown to be protected or shared at all?

Comment: Under file->Info->Permissions it says "Anyone can open, copy, and change any part of this workbook"

Comment: Does your ribbon agree with that choice as well? I just googled and it seems most people get everything grayed out if the workbook is being shared. I just want to rule that out

Comment: Also to rule some other things out and make sure I am not assuming anything.. is this on a brand new file? Is the place you are saving it somewhere local (not a network drive)?

Comment: So it looks like the ribbon changes after I re-open a saved file. The option to protect workbook vanishes. New excel file ribbon: https://i.imgur.com/Dt40ilW.jpg  Same file after saved and reopened ribbon: https://i.imgur.com/TxLnx5K.jpg

Comment: Is it saved locally? To somewhere common like the desktop? Is this a personal computer or a corporate one?

Comment: This is a brand new file that opens on opening excel. I've tried both locally and on network drives and both have same issue (In my post I save that file to the desktop). This is a corporate laptop.

Comment: Any add ons installed to Excel? Is your Excel verified to have a valid key? Can you try in Excel Safe Mode?  I really am running out of ideas tbh for what the problem could be... A reinstall of Excel may fix it but obviously that is not finding the actual problem and a pain.

Comment: I have a few add-ons, one was developed internally, and the other is PIDataLink (pulls in manufacturing data from historian).

Comment: Try disabling all addons to see if that changes the behavior at all

Comment: So, I disabled all of the add-ins and saved a new file. The issue still arises when I save and reopen the file... Note: the COM add-ins (PiDataLink) is still enabled when I re-open excel.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71079/discussion-between-bigchief-and-eric-f).

Comment: Have you restarted the computer?  Also, try using other formulas and see if any others change, or just that specific one.

Comment: Well, I feel like an idiot for not doing this sooner, but the reboot fixed the problem. Somehow even the files that I were changed and saved (like the one in example) have reverted back to the original cells referenced.

Comment: @BigChief Even though the reboot solved it (which I am glad it did), it is still a weird thing to have happen. Glad it worked out for you though!

Comment: @BigChief,, Check may be some MACRO with WORKBOOK_OPEN event is there !!